# How to solve "An error occured while verifying firmware" when updating to Mojave?

Tags: macos, mojave, software-update, internet-recovery

I just bought an early 2015 MacBook Pro that comes with macOS sierra. I want to update it to Mojave so i could run newer version of Xcode. But unfortunately i got this error everytime i tried to update it:

> An error occured while verifying firmware.

I tried to update it to High Sierra, but it does the same thing.

I borrowed my friend's bootable USB with High Sierra and change my SSD format to APFS, but it still gave me that error. I've tried to google for an answer and one of the forums that discussing this issue tells the original poster that it might have a problem regarding the logic board of the MBP. Which kinda freaked me out.

Why is this happening? And what should i do? Because i just switched to a mac from a windows laptop, so i still have zero knowledge about macos.

Comment: Do you have a good backup? This can be resolved easily with an erase and restore from internet recovery so you get fresh and correctly signed installers.

Comment: I don't need a backup fortunately because i don't have any data stored in the macbook. I did try the internet recovery but is it normal that i gives me os x yosemite when recovering the macos?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to get my installers from Apple, especially when I get an error with the download like you may have.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314

If your Mac is operational, absolutely get a good backup now before you attempt another install. That way you can escalate to an erase install which removes all your existing system and data and ensures if that install fails you know your hardware or network is the cause of the error.

Since yoU don’t need a backup, I would do the erase install and go to the latest possible.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904 (explains how to steer which version installs from recovery)
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255 (explains the overall process)
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208496 (erase steps - read last, start here)

Comment: I did try the internet recovery but is it normal that it gives me Yosemite when installing?

Comment: It depends which keys you hold - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255 and https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904 cover that. @llehcram Why not install any OS to get a good install the. Try the upgrade?

Comment: Out of frustration before asking on this thread i put my macbook to a third-party repair shop to get the update done. But i would take your answer if for some reason my macbook is still not willing to be upgraded. And i stumbled upon this thread :https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367695/cant-update-my-macbook-firmware , the case is exactly the same as i have right now, and one of the answers is advising to update via the sierra combo update. I hope that will work too. Are you willing to take more updates in this problem i'm having? Thank you so much for your answer

Comment: The linked post is the same steps as mine. Monomeeth and I and several others will be happy to answer more questions. Once you have the gear back , just ask a follow on question with exact build information